# Custom styling of views

Tags: java, android, xml, themes

I'm working on a survey application which dynamically creates `TextView` widgets. I've been trying all afternoon, without success, to find a way to encapsulate some styling behavior so I can just call it like `.setTextAppearance(context, *customStyle*)`, but I'm just not sure where to define or how to call the custom style.

Comment: By custom styles u mean your own style? or the ones provided by android?

Comment: What kind of styles do you want to create? Would you like to create custom themes, or just one single style for all of them?

Comment: Yup i mean like just having themes specifying size, color, etc of my textView so I can call that instead of specifying them each time. I'd like custom ones, so each type of widget can be tailored a little differently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create your custom style in some XML file in `res/values`, for example `res/values/styles.xml`:

```
<resources>
    <style name="CustomTextStyle" parent="android:style/TextAppearance">
         <item name="android:textColor">#f00</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Then to apply this style to your `TextView` in code:

```
 yourTextView.setTextAppearance(context, R.style.CustomTextStyle);
```

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I wanted to do.